# Not receiving Text Messages after upgrade to iOS 7

Tags: iphone, messages, ios, sms

Upgraded both iphone5s to ios7 approx two weeks back. Suddenly last Thurdays I cannot receive his texts. Phone calls and FaceTime yes. Texts no. He can receive texts from me. Any ideas?

Comment: http://support.apple.com/kb/TS2755?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US This place is here to help anyone that may have problems with their Apple products (software and hardware), but we do expect detailed questions. A lot of us take the time to help those that need it. We simply ask that you respect our time and include details that would help us do that. This also helps us better help you. You should try the troubleshooting tips in the link I provided. If nothing works, please edit your post to include more details (and what you have tried to fix the problem).

Answer (score 1):

I had something similar. To fix it, go to the Settings app, then General, then scroll down all the way to the bottom and tap Reset.

[image: Settings screen showing Reset]

This gives you various choices, but Reset Network Settings is what you want:

[image: Reset Network Settings]

you will then be given a confirmation to Reset Network Settings -- tap the text.

[image: Reset Network Settings Confirmation]

The phone will restart, and your Messages and texts should work fine. You may have to enter your WiFi passwords again, and on my phone, Mobile/Cellular, the toggle for Mobile Data / Cellular Data had been changed, so it may be an idea to check that.

Comment: I have had the same issue. But people not getting my iMessages. doing this solved my problem. But I think if the OP messages are being seen and the friends cannot. Then it would be the friend that needs to do this.

Comment: Agreed, i would suggest the friend should do this as well.