# Message send failure on iOS 7

Tags: ios, messages

I recently bought a iPod touch 5<sup>th</sup> generation and installed iOS 7. Whenever I try to send messages, I get a message failure notice. I checked Settings, Contacts, changed the DNS to 8.8.8.8 but nothing seems to fix the problem. Can you help?

Comment: Are you looking for the http://support.apple.com/kb/TS2755 so you can rule out some of the causes of this type of failure?

Comment: One thing you certainly should do is install iOS 8. Retry after that :)

Comment: Or iOS 9? You can't get 8 anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Try [resetting your network settings](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/104080/1067) - this fixes a variety of problems with Messages in iOS7. You shouldn't need to change your DNS, especially if you can browse the web normally with your existing DNS settings.